# building async httpbuilder similar to httpbuilder

Tags: java, asynchronous, groovy, neo4j, httpbuilder

Might be the wrong place to post this but I have been messing around with async http builders trying to get basic cypher queries to work.  It works with Http Builders but can't get it to work with the async version.

```
   @Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.6' )
    @Grab(group='net.sf.json-lib', module='json-lib', version='2.4', classifier='jdk15' )

    import groovyx.net.http.*
    import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
    import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*

    def query(statement, params,success, error) {
    def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://localhost:7474' )
    http.request( POST, JSON ) {
    uri.path = '/db/data/cypher/'
    headers.'X-Stream' = 'true'
    requestContentType = JSON
    body =  [ query : statement , params : params ?: [:] ]

     // uri.query = [ param : 'value' ]

     response.success = { resp, json ->
       if (success) success(json)
       else {
        println "Status ${resp.statusLine} Columns ${json.columns}\nData: ${json.data}"
       }
     }

     response.failure = { resp, message ->
           def result=[status:resp.statusLine.statusCode,statusText:resp.statusLine.reasonPhrase]
           result.headers = resp.headers.collect { h -> [ (h.name) : h.value ] }
           result.message = message
       if (error) {
                 error(result)
       } else {
        println "Status: ${result.status} : ${result.statusText} "
        println 'Headers: ${result.headers}'
        println 'Message: ${result.message}'
       }
     }
    }
   }
```

```
query("MATCH n RETURN n;",[],{ println "Success: ${it}" },{ println "Error: ${it}" })
```

However I have tried this with the `AsyncHttpBuilder`.  Couldn't get it to work.  Now I am trying a simple thing and have been unable to get it to give anytype of useful result.

```
@Test
public void testQueue()
{
    def http = new AsyncHTTPBuilder( poolSize : 1 ,
            uri : 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher' )
    def responses = []
    responses << http.post(query : [q:  "MATCH n RETURN n;"]) {return it}


    if (!responses.every{it.done})
    {
        println 'waiting...'
        Thread.sleep(2000)
    }
    responses.each {
        println(it)
    }
    http.shutdown()
}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: In last code piece, maybe you should do `while(!responces.every{it.done})`? Moreover, AsyncBuilder works same as Sync one,  it reports completion on responses callbacks.

Comment: So it will just tell me whether the request went through?

Comment: what happens when you run this test?

Comment: Look at the example here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/async.html, it shows how to wait for async request to complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for reference: I've answered this at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/neo4j/5Cle5vBsMXQ

> you need to pass in the cypher query in the request's body and not as
>   query param. See https://gist.github.com/sarmbruster/8114445 for a
>   working example